# Show that $f = g$ if $f,g : ℝ→ℝ$ are continuous and $f↾ℚ = g↾ℚ$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

[image]Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be two continuous functions. Suppose that $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb Q$.
Show that $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

For the question I defined h(x)=f(x)-g(x). For any given y and δ, there exists x∈R, such that |x−y|<δ. For any given ϵ, since h is continuous, h(y)−h(x)=h(y)<ϵ.
I kinda just blanked here as I was mostly copying down from book explanations at this point where i have my ϵ and δ, but don't know how to take those to show they are equal.

From the hints here I attached my attempted solution if anyone wants to look over it, not sure if i fully got it tbh.

Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation and re-fromat your question accordingly.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? For example, why do you think the logic of question 2 is "circular"? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. Here's a quick guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing. Notice I edited your question to improve the formatting. It is strongly advised that you use Mathjax to format your questions on this site - it's like LaTeX for the web. I edited your question this time since you are new, but in future, please format the question yourself. See here for a quick guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll show my work at the bottom with an edit now, and no worries about the downvote, I'm sure you're trying to keep the website clean ect. Thanks for the feedback! :)

Comment: I'll give learning the formatting a shot this eve, need to do it for next year any way and that page seems great to explain the notation.

Comment: You wrote "there exists $x \in D$", what is $D$? There's no $D$ in the problem. Don't just blindly copy other proofs.

Comment: You're bang on there mate sorry, was pretty blindly following textbook examples to get to that point, think with the comments i managed to make a better run at it, thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$. From the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ you can find a sequence $(q_n) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ such that $q_n \to x$. Can you use the continuity of $f$ and $g$ to conclude that $f(x)=g(x)$? Note that you can replace $\mathbb{Q}$ with any dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

The first step is good: set $h=f-g$, and now you have to prove that if $h$ is continuous and $h(x)=0$ for all $x\in \Bbb Q$, then $h(x)=0$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$.

Let $x\in \Bbb R$. Let's prove $h(x)=0$.

Let $\varepsilon >0$ be arbitrary. Since $h$ is continuous, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $y \in (x-\delta,x+\delta)$, we have $|h(x)-h(y)|< \varepsilon$. We may choose $y$ to be rational, then $h(y)=0$, and so $|h(x)|<\varepsilon$.

Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, this proves that $h(x)=0$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, went at it a different way slightly in the attached but I think it ended up the same place?

Comment: @Joe Thanks for the edit to correct grammar errors. I revert a change because I think it changed a little the logic of the answer. It's important to notice that you may choose $y$ rational. You wrote "If $y$ is rational..." but what if it's not? Also, I noticed that you changed \epsilon by \varepsilon, but not consistently.

Comment: @jwsedfWEFd Don't post images, please.

Comment: @jjagmath: No problem! I'm sorry I didn't change $\epsilon$ to $\varepsilon$ consistently, and I understand your point about choosing $y$ to be rational. I deleted my answer because I think it is essentially the same as yours, except that it is an indirect proof, which is non-optimal.

Comment: Sorry didnt know latex, thought an image would be better, i took a rational y because g(q)=f(q) for all x E Q is in the question, is that incorrect?

Comment: really sorry about the bad formatting also